# curl: download file with the same name with "-O" but defining a specific path directory

Tags: curl, options

With `curl` is possible do

```
curl http://somedomain.com/originalfilename.tar.gz -o newfilename.tar.gz
curl http://somedomain.com/originalfilename.tar.gz -o /other/path/newfilename.tar.gz
```

Therefore with `-o` is possible rename the filename to download and even define other path directort to download

Now if I want keep the same filename is mandatory use `-O`

```
curl http://somedomain.com/originalfilename.tar.gz -O
```

Therefore is downloaded the `originalfilename.tar.gz` file.

Now

**Question**

- How to download a file keeping its name (it with `-O`) *and* defining the directory to download?

Something like

```
curl http://somedomain.com/originalfilename.tar.gz -O <download to /some/path>
```

Therefore for Shell Scripting purposes, where the script can be executed in any place. I want download the `originalfilename.tar.gz` file explicitly at `/some/path`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You may specify the path to a directory where the document(s) you are fetching should be written using the `--output-dir` option.

That is,

```bash
curl -O --output-dir /some/path "$URL"
```

From the `curl` manual:

```
--output-dir <dir>

       This option specifies the directory in which files should be
       stored, when --remote-name or --output are used.

       The given output directory is used for all URLs and output
       options on the command line, up until the first -:, --next.

       If the specified target directory does not exist, the operation
       will fail unless --create-dirs is also used.

       If this option is used multiple times, the last specified
       directory will be used.

       Example:
        curl --output-dir "tmp" -O https://example.com

       See also -O, --remote-name and -J, --remote-header-name. Added
       in 7.73.0.
```